# Java Swing: how to stop unwanted shift-tab keystroke action

Tags: java, swing, focus

When I have a JTextField in a JPanel and it has focus, pressing "tab" doesn't do anything... but pressing "shift-tab" causes focus to be lost (FocusEvent.getOppositeComponent() is null).

If there are other focusable components on the JPanel (or rather under the "focus cycle root") this doesn't happen: instead, they get the focus on shift-tab.

In the SSCCE below I demonstrate this... each time you press Return in the search box you add a row to the JTable, which causes it to become focusable.  You can also uncomment the line which makes the JRadioButtons unfocusable.

I looked at the InputMaps as well to see whether shift-tab is somehow involved there ... not at all.

I also tried experimenting with FocusTraversalPolicy to see whether I could understand the problem. No joy.

My goal: to stop "shift-tab" causing a loss of focus (focus disappears) when there is a single focusable component in the focus cycle root's ambit.

*later*

a workaround is to add the line

```
if( oppComp == null ){ impl.searchBox.requestFocus(); }
```

at the end of the focusLost method of the search box's FocusListener ... but for me this is only a workaround... 1) it doesn't solve the problem through understanding of the focus traversal mechanism; 2) there might be circs when you would need the focus to be lost from the search box...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class BackTabProb {

    JFrame mainFrame;
    JTextField searchBox;
    JTable resultsTable;

    public static void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a_args) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        final BackTabProb impl = new BackTabProb();

        class Show implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                impl.mainFrame = new JFrame("Back Tab problem");
                impl.mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                        impl.mainFrame.dispose();
                    }

                });

                impl.resultsTable = new JTable();
                impl.resultsTable.setFocusable(false);
                Vector<Object> dataVector = new Vector<Object>();
                Vector<Object> colIdentifiers = new Vector<Object>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ONE", "TWO" }));
                ((DefaultTableModel) impl.resultsTable.getModel()).setDataVector(dataVector, colIdentifiers);
                JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(impl.resultsTable);
                JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
                northPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(northPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
                impl.searchBox = new JTextField("Enter search text", 10);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Search:");
                label.setLabelFor(impl.searchBox);
                northPanel.add(label);
                northPanel.add(impl.searchBox);
                ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
                ArrayList<JRadioButton> indexButtons = new ArrayList<JRadioButton>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    JRadioButton indexButton = new JRadioButton(i == 0 ? "Stemmer" : "Simple");

                    // commenting this out means back-tabbing from search box does not result
                    // in focus going "nowhere"
                    indexButton.setFocusable(false);

                    buttonGroup.add(indexButton);
                    northPanel.add(indexButton);

                }
                impl.mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                impl.mainFrame.getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                impl.mainFrame.getContentPane().add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                impl.mainFrame.pack();
                impl.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                print("=== visible");
            }
        }

        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Show());

        class AddMore implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                impl.mainFrame.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
                class SearchBoxFocusListener implements FocusListener {
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent focusEvent) {
                        print("=== search box got focus");
                        impl.searchBox.selectAll();

                    }

                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent focusEvent) {
                        Component oppComp = focusEvent.getOppositeComponent();
                        print(String.format("=== search box lost focus to %s",
                                oppComp == null ? "nowhere" : oppComp.getClass()));
                    }
                }
                impl.searchBox.addFocusListener(new SearchBoxFocusListener());

                class SearchBoxActionListener implements ActionListener {
                    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent actionEvent ){
                        if( actionEvent.getSource() != null ){
                            ((DefaultTableModel)impl.resultsTable.getModel()).insertRow( 0, new Object[]{ "blip", "blap" });

                            // as soon as the table has at least one row it is set to "focusable"

                            // commenting this out means back-tabbing from search box results
                            // in focus going "nowhere"
                            impl.resultsTable.setFocusable( true );
                        }
                    }
                }
                impl.searchBox.addActionListener( new SearchBoxActionListener() );

                ActionMap am = impl.searchBox.getActionMap();
                print("=== ActionMap");
                for (Object key : am.allKeys()) {
                    print(String.format("  === action key %s", key));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    print(String.format("=== InputMap type %d", i));
                    InputMap im = impl.searchBox.getInputMap(i);
                    KeyStroke[] allKeys = im.allKeys();
                    if (allKeys != null) {
                        for (KeyStroke ks : allKeys) {
                            print(String.format("  === keystroke %s object %s", ks, im.get(ks)));
                        }
                    }
                }

                // various experiments with FocusTraversalPolicy... NB LayoutTraversalPolicy
                // is what the framework uses here by default

                class MainFrameFocusTraversalPolicy extends LayoutTraversalPolicy {
                    public Component getComponentAfter(Container arg0, Component arg1) {
                        Component comp = super.getComponentAfter(arg0, arg1);
                        print(String.format("=== comp after %s", comp == null ? "Null" : comp.getClass()));
                        return comp;
                    }

                    public Component getComponentBefore(Container arg0, Component arg1) {
                        Component comp = super.getComponentBefore(arg0, arg1);
                        print(String.format("=== comp before %s", comp == null ? "Null" : comp.getClass()));
                        return comp;
                    }

                    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container arg0) {
                        Component comp = super.getDefaultComponent(arg0);
                        print(String.format("=== default comp %s", comp == null ? "Null" : comp.getClass()));
                        return comp;
                    }

                    public Component getFirstComponent(Container arg0) {
                        Component comp = super.getFirstComponent(arg0);
                        print(String.format("=== first comp %s", comp == null ? "Null" : comp.getClass()));

                        return comp;
                        // return impl.searchBox;
                    }

                    public Component getLastComponent(Container arg0) {
                        Component comp = super.getLastComponent(arg0);
                        print(String.format("=== last comp %s", comp == null ? "Null" : comp.getClass()));
                        return comp;
                    }

                    protected boolean accept(Component comp) {
                        boolean accept = super.accept(comp);
                        print(String.format("=== accept %s? %s", comp == null ? "Null" : comp.getClass(), accept));
                        return accept;
                    }
                }
                impl.mainFrame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new MainFrameFocusTraversalPolicy());
            }
        }
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new AddMore());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this still comes under the workaround heading for me... but it's a bit more useful than the workaround I gave under "later"

```
if( oppComp == null ){
    final Component srcComp = (Component)focusEvent.getSource();
    FocusTraversalPolicy ftp = impl.mainFrame.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
    Component lastComp = ftp.getLastComponent( impl.mainFrame );
    Component beforeComp = ftp.getComponentBefore( impl.mainFrame, srcComp );

    if( lastComp == beforeComp ){
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                if( impl.mainFrame.isFocused()){
                    srcComp.requestFocus();
                };
            }});
    }
}
```

Indeed, this is the situation faced by a single focusable component: on Shift-Tab the focus traversal policy then finds that the "before" comp is the same as the "last" comp.  Under these circs component focus (as opposed to window focus) appears to vanish.  The odd thing is that on Tab (traverse forwards), when the "after" comp is the same as the "first" comp, it doesn't.  Is this a bug?

Anyway, having ascertained this you then have to check the focus of the window asynchronously... so that focus can be allowed to go to another window. Results in a slight flicker (boo!) on Shift-Tab.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [Container#setFocusTraversalKeys(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setFocusTraversalKeys-int-java.util.Set-) method:

```
Set<AWTKeyStroke> backwardKeys = Collections.emptySet();
//alone JTextField(pointed out by @mKorbel): impl.mainFrame.setFocusTraversalKeys(
impl.searchBox.setFocusTraversalKeys(
    KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, backwardKeys);
```

Comment: right direction, JTextField hasn't TAB/Shift_TAB in KeyBindings, TextAction, then about (alone JTextField) Contianer

Comment: @aterai Thanks - but of course this completely disables tabbing in the backwards direction.

Comment: @aterai please to see this [question about JPanel and TAB event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24800417/714968)