# Setting custom focus key to exit focus of components like JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus

I want to set custom focus key in my application. Default is TAB. Sometime I need to omit for some component. Sometime need to reverse by another key. I find that when `JTable` gets focused. TAB only works and select within its row and never go outside the table. In my case, I need to change focus when all row has finished selection or a hot key to omit entire table.

Sometime I also need to implement system focus key as client already may habituate with it.

How can I achieve that easily?

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: Beware, people get very attached to the way that things work, start messing with it, and people can get very upset

Comment: hmmm, so thing is, when a JTextArea or JTable has focused another policy may start..Tab work smartly in JButton. But When a JTextArea get focused, then tab carries another meaning.... hmmm its looks like complicated to me now... :(

Comment: `Ctrl+Tab` will take focus out of the table and put it on the next focusable component (in either Windows or Metal PLAF).  Why stuff with that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Good point; for [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24809516/230513), `Ctrl+Tab` also has this effect on Mac OS X; "The `Control` key is used by convention to move the focus out of any component that treats `Tab` in a special way, such as `JTable`."

Comment: good point @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/KeyboardFocusManager.htm) is what you are looking for.

**note** :

```
Set<AWTKeyStroke> set =   p.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.UP_CYCLE_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
set = new HashSet(set);
KeyStroke up = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A");
```

Comment: But for issue of JTable that may not work for further forward...means that if any component has stay downside of a JTable. How could i go forward. TAB only select and re-select within its row.
you solve a part of my problem. thank you..